# I'm trying to import dataset files from current directory in python but getting Permission Error

Tags: python, numpy

```
import_directory = "./Dataset"
counter = 0
data_array = np.empty((0, 2))
files = os.listdir(import_directory)
for file in import_directory:
    print('Opening File : ', file)
    data_set = np.load(import_directory + file)
    data_array = np.vstack((data_array, data_set))
```

Error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './Dataset'`

folder structure

-------Project

----------Intrusion Detection System Deep Learning

----------Dataset

----------fyp.py

Comment: May be try to check that the file is not . or ..  . You should also use os.path.join to concat directory name and file name.

Comment: You didn't say in the question, so I have to ask: did you check that you have permission to read the directory and its contents outside Python? what does `ls -l Dataset` show?

Comment: @joanis I'm using VScode on windows. The files in dataset are NPY format as you asked I got  following:

**-a----        22-11-2021  08:50 PM      564096875 destinationPayload_TestbedMonJun14Flows.xml.npy**

Comment: @Ptit Xav I have multiple files which I want to iterate through

Comment: Where have you got error ? listdir or no.load ? in np.load use os.path.join(import_directory, file). Also ./Dataset can be written Dataset

Comment: @Ptit Xav In VScode terminal I'm getting error at 
`data_set = np.load(import_directory + file)` line

Comment: Can you print inport_directory and file ?

Comment: No I'm not able to print. @Ptit

Comment: You already have a print. Can you changed it to : print(“import file [{}] from directory [{}]”.format(file,import_directory))